# Find out if an int contains an element from an enum set using binary operations

Tags: java, enums, binary-operators

I am using a library that concatenates one or more enums by ORing their values like this:

```
    TestEnum {
        VAL1(0x00000001),
        VAL2(0x00000002),
        VAL3(0x00000100),
        VAL4(0x00000200),
        VAL5(0x00000400),
        VAL6(0x00000800),
        VAL7(0x00001000),
        VAL8(0x00002000),
        VAL9(0x00004000),
        VAL10(0x00008000),

        // special values
        VAL11(0x00000000),
        VAL12(0x00000010),
        VAL13(0x00000020),
        VAL14(0x00000030);

        private static final Map<Integer, TestEnum> TEST_ENUM_MAP;

        // constructor, populate map etc.

        public static TestEnum fromValue(final int value) {
            return TEST_ENUM_MAP.get(value);
        }
    }

    int valuesAsInt = 0;

    for (TestEnum testEnum : TestEnum.values()) {
        valuesAsInt |= testEnum.getValue();
    }
```

I need to extract the enums that were combined to produce `valueAsInt` keeping in mind that:

- The int MUST contain one of the special enum values (0x00000000...0x00000030)
- The int can contain zero or more of the non-special enum values.

This is what I did:

```
 private static final int MASK_FOR_SPECIAL_ENUMS = 0x000000FF;

 private static final ImmutableSet<TestEnum> SPECIAL_ENUMS = ImmutableSet.copyOf(Sets.newHashSet(TestEnum.VAL11, TestEnum.VAL12, TestEnum.VAL13, TestEnum.VAL14));

 private void lookupTestEnums(final int valueAsInt) {

      TestEnum testEnum = TestEnum.fromValue(valueAsInt & MASK_FOR_SPECIAL_ENUMS);
    if (testEnum == null || !SPECIAL_ENUMS.contains(testEnum)) {
        throw new ExceptionType("");
    }
 }
```

Just ANDing with the mask isn't sufficient because it'll return positive results for TestEnum values, `VAL1 (0x00000001)` etc.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure what you try to do, but just a tiny suggestion: use EnumSet instead of a set of Enums.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your `MASK_FOR_SPECIAL_ENUMS` must be equal to `0x000000F0`, *not* `0x000000FF`.

Then, after checking for validity, your lookup method needs to loop through values VAL1 through VAL10, and collect those that match.

In other words, something like this:

```
private static final int SPECIAL_MASK = 0x000000F0;

int specialValue = valueAsInt & SPECIAL_MASK;
int nonSpecialBits = valueAsInt & ~SPECIAL_MASK;
for (TestEnum testEnum : TestEnum.values()) 
{
    int value = testEnum.getValue();
    if( (value & SPECIAL_MASK) != 0 )
        continue; //this is one of the special values; ignore.
    if( (value & nonSpecialBits) == value )
        collection.add( testEnum );
}
```

Comment: I ran a quick test, it ended up in a different type of problem. `0x00000001 & 0x000000F0` is `0x00000000` which corresponds to a valid enum `VAL11`.

Comment: @user1071840 you need to negate the mask.  I amended my answer with an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not state that there can be **only** one special value; it states there *must be one*, which is another way of saying *at least one*, so it is not possible to do what you want, because:

```
0x00000010 | 0x00000020 == 0x00000030
```

Once `0x00000010` and `0x00000020` have been accumulated in the collective `OR` value, the value will be indistinguishable from an accumulated value that has `0x00000030` in it.

---

However, if the special value was `0x00000040`, a simple bit-mask would work.

Comment: the question says that there can only be one of the special enum values.

Comment: @Mike no, it doesn't. It says *MUST contain one of the special enum values*, which doesn't preclude having more than one. If OP wanted what you claim, OP should have used the magic word you did: "only", ie *MUST contain **only** one of the special enum values*, but OP did not.

Comment: @Bohemian you're right. I had misinterpreted the requirement

Comment: @user1071840 so, what is the requirement? Exactly one special or at least one special?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm trying to clarify the requirement